# broken prepared statement for insert

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this prepared statement isn't working.

```
$thisInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO conversations (person_a, person_b, exchange_count, inbox) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$thisInsert->bind_param('iiii', $activeUser, $passiveUser, 1, 1);
$thisInsert->execute();
```

Comment: Does `$thisInsert->error()` yield any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values are bound **by reference**, not by value; so you can't bind a value like `1`, only something like a variable containing the value that you want to bind

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (my emphasis)

> **Note** that mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be ***passed by reference***